# Stripe - Create Checkout Session with Stripe Connect

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I'm trying to implement a checkout procedure for non-authenticated customers using the below logic:

1. Collect customer email
2. Generate Stripe customer using below logic:

   ```
   const customer = await stripe.customers
    .create({
        email,
        name,
    })
    .then((customer) => customer)
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        return null;
    });
   ```
3. Create token to pass account to my Stripe Connect business partner account.

   ```
   const tempCustomerToken = await stripe.tokens.create(
            {
                customer: customerAccId,
            },
            {
                stripeAccount: vendorStripeAcc,
            }
        );
   ```
4. Create customer on business partner's acc.

   ```
   const tempCustomer = await stripe.customers.create(
            {
                source: tempCustomerToken.id,
            },
            {
                stripeAccount: vendorStripeAcc,
            }
        );
   ```
5. Create checkout session using customer ID from business partner's acc.

   ```
   const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create(
            {
                payment_method_types: ['card', 'alipay'],
                customer: tempCustomer.id,
                line_items: items,
                success_url: 'https://example.com/success',
                cancel_url: 'https://example.com/cancel',
                payment_intent_data: {
                    application_fee_amount: 50
                },
            },
            {
                stripeAccount: vendorStripeAcc,
            }
        );
   ```

This is failing on Step 2 with this error - `The customer must have an active payment source attached.`

However, I want the customer to supply their payment method during the `Stripe Checkout` session, therefore when I create the customer I don't want to ask them for any payment info.

Is there a way to achieve the following:

1. Create Stripe customer with email and no payment method on my Stripe acc.
2. Share this customer with `Stripe Connect` business partner.
3. Allow the customer to use `Stripe Checkout` session to make a `direct` purchase on the `Stripe Connect` business vendor account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flow you are describing is used when you want to have a customer and a card on the platform account and then clone that card on the connected account to accept a one-time payment. The idea is that as a platform you collect card details once and can accept future payments on behalf of third-party vendors for example.

The customer in the platform and the one on the connected account are not related or linked in any way when you do this. They are just 2 separate objects and you would be able to clone the card once to avoid collecting the card details again.

In your example though you don't have a card nor do you want to collect one. This means there's no reason to create a customer on the platform account or try to clone it on the connected account. You seem to only want to accept a payment on the connected account.

You should skip all the steps entirely and instead just create a Checkout Session on the connected account. As you go through Checkout it will collect card details, accept the payment and also create a Customer for you on the connected account to save the card details for future payments.

You won't be able to use that customer on the platform nor its card, but that part is expected with the way Stripe Connect is built.